# ios 10: Push notification - change the text of button "View"

Tags: objective-c, button, push-notification, action, ios10

In iOS version 9 and below of my app, I added 2 action buttons and upon sliding the notification I see options - action1 and action 2 as desired. However in ios 10 I see 2 buttons with text "View" and "Clear" and upon clicking on "View" I am able to see the customized buttons I added.

1) Is there any way that I see the buttons I added directly without clicking on "View"?
2) Is there any way I can change the text of "View"[image]?

Comment: Did u get the answer?

Comment: Nope. I guess it can not be changed as other apps like Whatsapp also shows this button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,.

Comment: if the device is having 3D touch support, then you won't find that View at all!
it will directly direct us to custom actions. otherwise on clicking "View" displays the custom actions so we cant change the "view" button